# Is it possible to set FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE on an activity, but also close the activity when a touch occurs?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I would like to set `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` on a transparent activity to allow interaction with the activity below. Is there any way to close the transparent activity when a user touches the screen while these flags are set?

Comment: You can call finish() in the activity that is transparent. But don't you think you are probably better with a View on top of you activity?

Comment: Yes I can call finish() on the transparent activity. I want to know if I can trigger the call to finish() off the touch, even with FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE set.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you'd be able to determine if the user touched the screen if `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` is set. Your Activity will simply not receive any touch events at all.

Instead, what you can do is set an `onTouchListener` to the root View, then return `false` indicating that you do not want to handle the touch. This way, you'll always receive the first touch event (`ACTION_DOWN`) which allows you to call `finish()` and go.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can.

```java
// not any touch event
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```